# IvoryGoogleMap - can't display infoWindow

Tags: symfony

i'm trying to use [IvoryGoogleMap](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle) to display a simple map with markers and infoWindows using this code:

```
$marker     ->setPosition($place->getLat(), $place->getLng());
$infoWindow ->setContent('<p>Default content</p>');
$marker     ->setInfoWindow($infoWindow);
$map        ->addMarker($marker);
```

and all i'm getting is a map with marker(s) but when i click on one of them, nothing happens. Have you any idea what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. Here is the solution from bundle's author **egeloen** (on [github](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/issues/3#issuecomment-2023911)):

======================================================================

This functionality doesn't exist natively. If you want to open an info window with a click event on a marker, you need to use the `ivory_google_map.event` service. This service allow you to generate all events you want.

In your case, the event is :

```
$clickEvent = $this->get('ivory_google_map.event');
$clickEvent->setInstance($marker->getJavascriptVariable());
$clickEvent->setEventName('click');
$clickEvent->setHandle(sprintf('function(){%s.open(%s, %s);}',
    $infoWindow->getJavascriptVariable(),
    $map->getJavascriptVariable(),
    $marker->getJavascriptVariable()
);

$map->getEventManager()->addEvent($clickEvent);
```